# Fetch all file paths from documents directory iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

THere are two files downloaded from my app. one was successful and another one is failed. whenever i try to fetch all file paths , i am only getting succesful download urls instead of all.

This is how am fetching file paths

```
NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *urlsArray = [fileMan URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSAllDomainsMask];
NSLog(@"urls %@",urlsArray);
```

This is how i am downloading videos.

```
NSString *uriString = [[streamlistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"URI"];
    NSString *baseUrlString = [[streamlistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"BaseUrl"];
    NSString *downloadUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseUrlString,uriString];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *urlSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
    // Create a new AVAssetDownloadURLSession with background configuration, delegate, and queue
    AVAssetDownloadURLSession *avAssetDownloadSession = [AVAssetDownloadURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:urlSessionConfiguration assetDownloadDelegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    AVURLAsset *hlsAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadUrlString]];

    if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {

        //[AVAssetDownloadTaskMediaSelectionKey: mediaSelection]
        avAssetVidDownloadTask = [avAssetDownloadSession assetDownloadTaskWithURLAsset:hlsAsset assetTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] assetArtworkData:nil options:nil];
        [avAssetVidDownloadTask resume];

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Please check the below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: try this : [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"" error:nil];

Comment: app is crashing at that line

Comment: did u insert your path in contentsOfDirectoryAtPath ?

Comment: oops i didnt ..., infact i dont know the exact path of root, please check the screenshottt